# GCC cannot find package libusb-dev

Tags: gcc

Trying to compile pymini,[Eckler Software](http://www.ecklersoft.com/download.shtml) on RPI3, Ubuntu Mate 16.04
I get the following output of ./configure with error:
    configure: error: cannot find libusb-devel 1.0 support

```
tim@tim-desktop:~/pymini-1.16$ ./configure

    checking build system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
    checking host system type... armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking minix/config.h usability... no
    checking minix/config.h presence... no
    checking for minix/config.h... no
    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
    checking "for canonical host"... "Linux/Unix"
    checking for mini build... yes
    checking for pow in -lm... yes
    checking pthread.h usability... yes
    checking pthread.h presence... yes
    checking for pthread.h... yes
    checking libusb.h usability... no
    checking libusb.h presence... no
    checking for libusb.h... no
    configure: error: cannot find libusb-devel 1.0
```

I installed libusb-dev and ran configure again
and configure failed again with same error
I installed libusb-1.0-0-dev and ran configure again
and configure failed again with same error
I then did some goole serching and tried a little investigation on the install of libusb with the following commands

```
sudo dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0-dev

     /.
     /usr
     /usr/lib
     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.a
     /usr/include
     /usr/include/libusb-1.0
     /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
     /usr/share
     /usr/share/doc
     /usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev
     /usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/copyright
     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so
     /usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/README
     /usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

And also:

```
sudo dpkg -L libusb-dev

    /.
    /usr
    /usr/include
    /usr/include/usb.h
    /usr/bin
    /usr/bin/libusb-config
    /usr/share
    /usr/share/doc-base
    /usr/share/doc-base/libusb-dev
    /usr/share/man
    /usr/share/man/man1
    /usr/share/man/man1/libusb-config.1.gz
    /usr/share/doc
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/copyright
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-return-values.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.core.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-synchronous.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-overview.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-timeouts.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/preface.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetaltinterface.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.deviceops.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbcontrolmsg.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.control.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkwrite.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-device-interfaces.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.bulk.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.interrupt.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclaiminterface.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclose.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-other.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbresetep.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-types.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfinddevices.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbdetachkerneldrivernp.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdescriptor.html       
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-support.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/htm/function.usbgetdescriptorbyendpoint.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclearhalt.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdrivernp.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/index.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbopen.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptread.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.nonportable.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/functions.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfindbusses.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptwrite.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-tests.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstring.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkread.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstringsimple.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-code.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreleaseinterface.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetbusses.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetconfiguration.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreset.html
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinit.html
    /usr/lib
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.so
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb.a
    /usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

then I tried:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
```

then rerun configure and it failed with same error
so I also tried:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
```

then re-run configure and it failed with same error
I also ran:

```
`pkg-config --modversion libusb-1.0
    1.0.20
 pkg-config --modversion libusb
    0.1.12
```

I then uninstalled libusb-dev leaving only libusb-1.0-0-dev installed.
Then tried running configure again with same error

```
    configure: error: cannot find libusb-devel 1.0
```

Then I tried adding to ~.bashrc

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
```

What is going on here, cannot figure it out would appreciate some help

tjmarch

Answer (score 0):

try: 

`pkg-config --modversion libusb-dev`

I don't think pkg-config-path is a command.  There is PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, this "pymini" package doesn't try to discover the path or other flags to libusb itself properly.  You need to give it some extra flags for that, which you can see referenced in the comments for configure.ac

```
# Notes on compiling on Ubuntu.
#
#     ./configure --prefix=/usr CFLAGS="-g -Wall -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0" CXXFLAGS="-g -Wall -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0" (Ubuntu 12.04)
#
#     make
#     make install
```

You are on the right track.  libusb-1.0-0-dev is the package you need (and not libusb-dev, which is different), at which point the commands from configure.ac above should just work as is.

A "nicer" version using pkg-config which you were trying would be something like this.

```
pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags
./configure --prefix=/usr CFLAGS="$(pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags)" CXXFLAGS="$(pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags)"
```

Normally you would also set LIBS=$(pkg-config libusb-1.0 --libs) however that is hard coded into this project already so it's not needed in this specific case.